# AWS SES SMTP AuthenticationFailedException: 220 Ready to start TLS

Tags: java, email, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I followed the instructions in the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/ses/latest/dg/send-email-smtp.html) to create the SMTP credentials and downloaded the .csv file of the credentials; but When I sent an email using SMTP in Java code (Open JDK 1.8), I received an exception.

my dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

my code:

```
private static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    private static final String PORT = "587";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "SMTP user name in credentials.csv";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "SMTP password in credentials.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
            }
        });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("faxon.xing@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("AWS SES SMTP Email");
        message.setContent("<p>Hello, AWS SES SMTP<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">click btn</a></p>", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        Transport.send(message);
    }
```

Exception log:`Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 220 Ready to start TLS`

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Comment: Xon Fa - Next time, could you include a comment mentioning why this is a solution? It'll help others when looking for similar problems in the future. From my prior work with this area, I'm betting that the mail server you were connecting to had problems with the TLS protocol (TLSv1.1 was recently deprecated / removed from the JVM and if that's what it was initially negotiated as - it could lead to an error like this (stack trace would have highlited it)).